How to make many layer icon for SwiftUI / visionOS app?
I did set a white homogeneous image for the Back image the Middle and Front image is the logo, made by designer. But still I do not see that parallax effect. What else I can do?


It's a very subtle effect. Are you sure nothing's happening? Your screenshot has clipped the part where you add the image to the Asset.
